# how to mock mongodb in Angularjs unit test?

Tags: angularjs, mongodb, unit-testing

Just as title, I want write unit test for a function in angular js. this function is insert data into Mongo db. The code is as following:

```
function addDatasource(brandId, data, callback) {
    var payload = _.assign(data, {brandId:brandId});
    mongo.db().collection('datasources').insert(payload, callback);
}
```

I think to test such code, I need to mock MongoDB. I searched internet but didnot find any. Anyone can help me with this?

Comment: Are you connecting database directly from client? Do you have a publicly available database?

Comment: Not really clear which case you are asking for here. A: How to mock the datasource on the client ( browser ) or B: How to mock on the server interface. In either case, there are packages available and various options. For the client the simple case would be to swap the injected service with something that just returns mock data. This also basically reads as "asking for library recommendations" which puts the question clearly "off-topic" for here. If you choose a library and asked for help with that, then that question is allowed.

Comment: @BlakesSeven  I want to write unit test for the code I offered in my question. I do not know how and search google for 'angularjs test mock mongodb' and read first 5 pages and do not find any library for it. I am not so sure what you mean. If you have any clone about how to do the unit test for the code I offer, please simply just offer me either the idea, keyword or any code. Thx.

Comment: @KirillSlatin I am not so sure how to make this question clear. I only want to know how to write unit test for the function I mentioned in my question and I think I need mock the mongodb for testing it. Please let me know if you think I do not need to mock it when test this function.

Comment: From the fact that it's Angular code I conclude that you're testing client code. This pretty wrong approach to access DB directly from client code so I don't think you can find any library for mocking mongoDB on client side. Thus you're right, you need a mock and you will have to write it on your own